# download of Lubuntu 32 bit 18.04

Tags: lubuntu, 18.04

I downloaded 2 times and got 64 bit Lubuntu.  I think there is an error and the wrong file is in the link.
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04/release/

Comment: The 64bit Lubuntu is there too. Make sure you get the correct image.

Comment: I cannot add the appropriate tag because although I programmed for 45 years I do not know enough.

Comment: Please run the following command and post the result. It will indicate what file you are getting when you try: `md5sum file.iso` where you replace 'file.iso` with the actual file name of your Lubuntu iso file. Did you try direct download or torrent?

Comment: the name says 64 and I loaded it on an iso dvd and it did not install because it really is 64.  I loaded it on a flash and it gave me an error message that it could not install.  Guess what it says it is 64 and it isn't lying.

Comment: It worked.  Thanks.  Now I have to delete 4 amd64 files from my downloads directory.

Comment: @AmanMittal: That's not a comment!  That's an answer.  Please answer the question and ping me and I'll come back and upvote!  **:-)**

Comment: @Fabby yeah sure. Done.

Answer (score 4):

It's easier to go to [lubuntu's homepage](https://lubuntu.net/) site where it'll be obvious where the 32-bit version is or just click [this link](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04/release/lubuntu-18.04-desktop-i386.iso) copy-pasted from there on here for your convenience.